# Is it possible for vue-apollo to return different results from the Playground?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, nuxt.js, vue-apollo, graphql-playground

I have a GraphQL query called `myAccounts` which returns an array of accounts.  When I go to the Playground and call the query:

```
{
    accounts {
        email
    }
}
```

I get this result:

```
"data": {
    "accounts": [
        {
            "email": "zach@email-one.com",
        },
        {
            "email": "zach@email-two.com",
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I am in my Component, `vue-apollo` returns two items in the array, but seems to overwrite the second item with the first.  Here is the query (in `MyAccounts.gql`):

```
query myAccounts {
    accounts: myAccounts {
        email
    }
}
```

and here is the Apollo query in the component:

```
import MY_ACCOUNTS_QUERY from '~/apollo/queries/MyAccounts'
...
apollo: {
    accounts: {
        query: MY_ACCOUNTS_QUERY,
        result(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        }
    }
}
```

and here is what `vue-apollo` logs out through the `result`:

```
{
   "data":{
      "accounts":[
         {
            "email":"zach@email-one.com",
            "__typename":"Account"
         },
         {
            "email":"zach@email-one.com",
            "__typename":"Account"
         }
      ]
   },
   "loading":false,
   "networkStatus":7,
   "stale":false
}
```

**Expected behavior**
I would expect the data returned in the Playground to be identical to what `vue-apollo` is fetching.

**Versions**
vue: `2.6.10`
vue-apollo: `@nuxtjs/apollo: 4.0.0-rc18`

**Additional context**
I thought the `result` hook would be the best way to debug, but any other suggestions gladly welcomed.  I assumed that this was a bug in our code, but I cannot figure out what could be causing the repetition (and mismatch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apollo normalizes its cache based on the `__typename` and the `id` (or `_id`) field. You need to include an `id` or `_id` field in your selection set alongside `email`. Failing to do so results in both objects being assigned the same key. If you don't have an `id` field to request, you'll need to provide a custom `dataIdFromObject` function as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#custom-identifiers).

Comment: Thanks for linking to the `dataIdFromObject` function.  That is helpful to know about.

Comment: An update that `dataIdFromObject` is deprecated in favor of the `keyFields` option of the `TypePolicy` object. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#customizing-identifier-generation-by-type

Answer (score 0):

From Guillaume Chau (https://github.com/Akryum):

> This is because the Apollo Client cache can't compute a different ID
>   for the two items, so you endup with Account:undefined (or similar)
>   for both. Open the Apollo devtools and look at the myAccounts key in
>   the cache.
>
> Learn more:
>   https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/